# Нахождения площади с картинки

Tags: python, opencv

Есть изображение формата А4 (пример в конце будет). Внизу изображении есть фигура (она может быть вообще любого формата, но она рисуется в +- на том же месте). Задача в том, чтобы программа находила площадь данных фигур! У меня пока что даже нету идей как реализовать, так как фигура может быть и не кругом и не квадратом и не многоугольником и т.д. Кто может реализовать данную задумку?

[image: Пример]

Comment: по видимому вам нужна функция `findContours`. Для ее применения вам будет нужно вырезать область с фигурой, перевести в бинарный формат и скормить функции. Главное, чтобы фигура была замкнута и была одна (иначе придется выяснять какой фигуре принадлежат вычесленные контуры)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если фигура замкнутая, цвет границы отличается от фона, и известна некая внутренняя точка, то проще всего воспользоваться алгоритмом [Flood-fill](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) для нахождения количества пикселов внутри границы.

Если про внутреннюю точку точно сказать нельзя, то можно сканировать изображение по строкам снизу вверх (для данного случая), пока не найдётся граничная точка.

(Можно также обойти и границу, получив площадь внутренней области по shoelace формуле, но этот обход может быть сложнее, если граница неидеальная (как на рисунке справа-сверху))

Comment: А можно как нибудь сетку по верх картинки поставить, допустим квадраты 1см или 1мм? Или пиксель это и есть как 1мм?

Comment: Пиксель представляет некую площадь, зависящую от разрешения изображения, поэтому нужно знать dpi - количество точек на дюйм.